# Sorting tuples with respect to multiple criteria

Tags: algorithms, data-structures, optimization, sorting, partitions

Given $n$ rows with $k$ columns, is there a storage mechanism/data-structure and/or algorithm that enables dynamic restructuring such that I can get the top $t=\mathcal{O}(1)$ results efficiently?

#### Example strategy 0

$$k_0 \le k_1 \le \cdots \le k_{n-2} \le k_{n-1}$$

#### Example strategy 1

$$k_{n-1} \le k_{n-2} \le \cdots \le k_1 \le k_0$$

---

Given `[ [0,1] [2,3] [1,2] ]` strategy 0 returns: `[ [0,1], [1,2] ]`, where $t=2$.

Restructuring with strategy 1 returns: `[ [2,3], [1,2] ]`. New strategies can be provided "at runtime".

---

Given a data-structure solution, here are the methods that it should expose:

- `insert_row (*row) ->` inserts a row of $k$ elements into the structure
- `delete_row (*row) ->` delete the precisely specified row from structure
- `new_strategy(*k_prioritisation) ->` rebalances the structure given the specified strategy
- `top_rows() ->` provides top rows after a strategy has been "installed". Number of rows to return is specified at compile time (as a source-code constant).

---

PS: Bonus points if you can enables strategies like $k_0 \le [\text{all other } k \text{ except } k_0]$, with embedded strategies of much the same.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is the input (including the runtime constraints), and what is the output? Your example can be solved using sorting in various ways.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Better now?

Comment: What do you mean by "the weights should propagate down"?  What criteria should be used to determine which weights to change, and how?  What do you mean by "conflicts are resolved through strict priorities"?  Can you define what you mean by "optimal row"?  Optimal in what sense?  The problem does not seem to be well-specified.  Before one can start thinking about an algorithm, the very first step is to make sure you have a precise specification of the algorithmic problem you want solved.

Comment: @Raphael, no, unfortunately, I still find it unclear (however I can no longer vote to put it on hold until it is clarified, now that it's been re-opened).  The question still does not describe  what is the desired output and what are the running time constraints (as Yuval suggested).

Comment: @D.W. I find it clear now; in essence, the goal is to sort w.r.t. an order relation specified by "in column x, smaller/larger is better". There is no runtime restriction, but there does not have to be one.

Comment: @Raphael, OK, glad it made sense to you.  Perhaps you could edit the question based on your understanding?  I don't see a specification of an order relation in the question -- and the answer will depend on what order relation the poster has in mind.  The question doesn't define what it means by an "optimal row".  Apparently the choice of which row is optimal somehow depends upon some weights and/or priorities, but it's not clear to me where those come from or how they affect which row will be optimal.

Comment: I have edited the question to be much clearer.

Comment: 1. I don't understand your strategies.  You show an equation, but what is the equation supposed to mean?  What's $k_i$?  What's the definition of $\le$?  Are you trying to represent [lexicographic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) of the rows, under some permutation of the columns, where each strategy corresponds to a different permutation?  Please define all symbols and terms before first use.  2. What do you mean by "the top results"?  "top" under what ordering relationship?  3. Where do the strategies come from?  Are they inputs?  What's an embedded strategy?

Comment: 4. You ask for a data structure.  A helpful way to specify a data structure is to list the operations that the data structure needs to support, and specify how each operation should affect the data structure and/or what it should return.  Can you do that for your problem statement?

Comment: I've answered a couple of your clarification questions.

Answer (score 1):

Multivariate optimisation (a subproblem of sorting) is usually hard, even offline, because there are no longer "optima" but you have to deal with several Pareto-optimal elements.

Luckily, you have specified that such ties should be broken by strict priorities. In that case, lexicographic sorting (w.r.t. your criteria and in order of the priorities) solves the problem.

Comment: Also one other approach I was considering: 0) Setup k priority queues 1) Iterate over rows, applying weights as you go 2) Pick the top relevant entry in each column. Data-structure: finger tree.